# Bashrc needs restarting every time I open a new window

Tags: bash

I need to run

```
. ~/.bashrc
```

every time I open a new terminal window for bash to recognize my

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may need to have your `~/.bash_profile` source your `~/.bashrc`.  I have this in my `~/.bash_profile`:

```bsh
if [[ -f ~/.bashrc ]] ; then
    . ~/.bashrc
fi
```

If you don't have that, add it and try again.

Comment: I have the same problem with my ~/.bash_profile now, I need to run it on every window.

Comment: @mtheorylord Is your login shell actually `bash`? What does `echo "$SHELL"` output?

Comment: Yeah, I was using zsh, I made the modifications necessary and it worked now. Thanks.